# Which database should I use for my flutter app using lots of images?

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to build a flutter app which focuses on learning plant names with the help of a lot of pictures. In total there will be 600-800 pictures.

1. question: Do I store these pictures all in the app or in a database?

From what I read so far I guess the app would be too big if I store all these pictures in the app.

2. question: Which database should I use for storing such an amount of pictures?

I want to give the possibility to store a lection/course (containing 30-40 pictures) locally on the phone to be able to learn without internet connection.

3. question: Which database should I use for that?

Answer (score 2):

> Question #1: Do I store these pictures all in the app or in a
> database?

You should not store all the images in your app. Use the [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/start) service to store your pictures and download them to your app as desired.

> Question #2: Which database should I use for storing such an amount of pictures?

You should use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/start) to store your pictures: "Cloud Storage for Firebase is built for app developers who need to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos."

> Question #3: I want to give the possibility to store a section/course (containing 30-40 pictures) locally on the phone to be
> able to learn without internet connection. Which database should I use
> for that?

You can save these pictures locally as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files#download_to_a_local_file) in the Firebase doc: "The `writeToFile()` method downloads a file directly to a local device. Use this if your users want to have access to the file while offline."

Comment: Hey @Valentin, did you have time to look a the proposed answer?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks a lot! I have an additional question. What would be the best approach to communicate with a Firebase Cloud Storage for my rather simple and small app? Should I go for a direct connection via Dart code or consider a backend written in Java or Python for example.

Comment: Hello, I would advise to use the Flutter/Dart plugin. The model of Firebase is to directly interact between your app (mobile or web) and the serverless backend services offered by Firebase (Cloud Storage, Firestore, Auth service, etc.). No need for a middleware

Answer (score 0):

1. If in a database, get pic to many times, and much more than the free limit of database , we will prefer pic in app than in database.
   But in app will never consider the cost, just keep the develop account. Maybe, a pic could compress down to 50kb each, and the app will not too big to download.
2. mongodb google-could amazon ... all database on the market can serve you.
3. above dbs are good. the more resourses on net, the better envirnment we like.